# cytoscape-d3-force layout and radial force

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I'm experimenting the d3-force layout extension with cytoscape.js at https://observablehq.com/@nfigay/cytoscape-3d-force-layout-testing-for-a-notebook, trying to take advantage of radial force, as shown in the following observable notebook at https://observablehq.com/@nfigay/a-tutorial-to-using-d3-force-from-someone-who-just-learned-ho#radial_sect.

However, despite multiple attempt, I didn't find how to obtain a similar simulation, it seems that a central force applies.

```
var cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById("myGraph"),
    layout: {
      name: "d3-force",
      animate: true,
      fixedAfterDragging: false,
      linkId: function id(d) {
        return d.id;
      },
      //linkDistance: 80,
      // manyBodyStrength: -800,
      radialX: 0,
      radialY: 0,
      radialRadius: 200,
      radialStrength: 1,
      //  xStrength: 0.0001,
      //  yStrength: 0.0001,
      //manyBodyStrength: -800,
      //collideRadius: 10,
      //collideStrength: 1,
      fit: false,
      ready: function () {},
      stop: function () {},
      tick: function (progress) {
        console.log("progress - ", progress);
      },
      randomize: false,
      infinite: false
    },
```

[results on a set of nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCwtd.png)
[what is expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpZmb.png)

Did someone already used radial force with this layout successfully?

Comment: play with parameters such as `radialX`, `radialRadius` etc ...

Comment: It 's what I did, but always with the same inappropriate resource. So I'm short of ideas. Did you already suceedeed?

Comment: your problem is totally on layout extension. It is the one that sets the positions of the nodes

Comment: I know. However I don't know if it is just an issue with parameterization of this published layout extension, or if it is a problem with the implementation. Before to go and explore the code, I first prefer to collect feedback in order to know if someone succeeded in using  this published layout the way I want to use it.